# Is there a way to keep vehicle from flipping when jumped from ramp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a stunt game where vehicle will jump from ramps but unfortunately it keeps leaning forward when in air which makes bad landing I have struggled but can't stop it from doing this.
I'm using RCC V3 for car.

`vehicle.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(vehicle.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(-5f, vehicle.transform.rotation.y, vehicle.transform.rotation.z), Time.deltaTime * 2f);`

I have used this line of code which stops it from leaning forward but `vehicle.transform.rotation.y` this doesn't working properly which makes the car to rotate 180 degree on y axis.

can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Tbh that is a natural thing for a car todo!

Comment: I know but I want it not to do this. is there any way around?

Comment: Apply minor force to the back end

Comment: how can I do that I actually don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following suggestion for solving your problem.
Shortly, you gradually increase the pitch while in the air.

```
private IEnumerator RotationSequence()
{
    while (!grounded)
    {
        Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(m_EulerAngleVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidbody.rotation * deltaRotation);
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. by doing this vehicle becomes glitchy while in air.

Comment: Oh silly me. I did not accounted that it is a `Rigidbody`. Have found the following [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html). Will update the answer using this method.

Comment: It makes the rotation smooth but still don't stop at zero it keeps on rotating.

Comment: you should set bool variable `grounded` properly to stop it rotating. Or make a condition that will suit you.

Comment: ok I will try to figure out with it Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following:

```
m_Rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
```

when your car is flying, then you can set to false when it's landed.

Comment: this will not work properly because it will freeze all rotation but I don't want that

Comment: So what do you want? stop the rotation only for a certain axis?

Comment: I want x axis to smothly become zero

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could set the pivot of the car to a different place while its in midair

Comment: I have moved the COM to back it helped a little bit but I'm not satisfied I want the results like in few games where car automatically performs flip and cool stuff while in air but I'm not even able to make it straight how would I do that